# Not changing result on flutter ui

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I'm trying to make an application using open ai API. When I send a request for the first time it shows the result. But second time it doesn't change results. But after restarting it works fine. How do I fix it? Is there any state update issue? I Just made it for practice. And so I didn't make any design here. Just used the logic

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_2/api-service/ApiModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_2/api-service/service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isTyping = false;

  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();

  ApiClass apiObj = ApiClass();
  List<ApiModel> chatList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Chat GPT",
      theme: ThemeData(
          textSelectionTheme:
              TextSelectionThemeData(selectionHandleColor: Colors.transparent)),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
          child: AppBar(
            title: Text("AI ChatBot"),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text(textController.text),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: chatList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return AnimatedTextKit(
                    animatedTexts: [
                      TypewriterAnimatedText(
                          chatList[index].message!.content.toString(),
                          speed: Duration(milliseconds: 50))
                    ],
                    totalRepeatCount: 1,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            if (isTyping) ...[
              SpinKitThreeBounce(
                size: 18,
                color: Colors.grey,
              )
            ],
            TextField(
              controller: textController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                hintText: "Type your question here...",
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      setState(() {
                        isTyping = true;
                      });
                      
                      chatList = await apiObj.sentData(textController.text);
                      setState(() {
                        isTyping = false;
                      });
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.send)),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.grey,
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              cursorColor: Colors.amber,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Api Service Code :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'ApiModel.dart';

class ApiClass {
  Future<List<ApiModel>> sentData(msg) async {
    Response response =
        await post(Uri.parse('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'),
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer $ApiCode',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: jsonEncode({
              "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
              "messages": [
                {"role": "user", "content": msg.toString()}
              ],
              "temperature": 0.7
            }));

    Map<String,dynamic>json = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<dynamic> jsonData = json['choices'];
    List<ApiModel> sendChat =
        jsonData.map((e) => ApiModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    return sendChat;
  }
}
```

Comment: If i use future builder then it shows a error

Comment: The code you posted in the question has a FutureBuilder without a future.  I would have thought the future passed to FutureBuilder would be the un-awaited result the API was returning.

Comment: @JohnWeidner sorry i posed wrong code...now i edited which i actually wrote

Comment: Please include your ApiClass code in the question. I added a mocked out version of the ApiClass and the rest of the app seemed to work how I think you were intending it to.

Comment: @JohnWeidner ok ...now i added Api service code ... kindly check

Comment: @JohnWeidner json response is ok ! but my problem in changing state

Answer (score 0):

It seems like AnimatedTextKit is not refreshing.  You might add a key to it to force it to refresh when the value changes.  For example:

```
return AnimatedTextKit(
           key: ValueKey(chatList[index].message!.content.toString()),
           animatedTexts: [
               TypewriterAnimatedText(
                chatList[index].message!.content.toString(),
                speed: Duration(milliseconds: 50))
           ],
           totalRepeatCount: 1,
       );
```

Here is a video that discussed when you need keys.  https://youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc?si=q36Zm2glYQBOIW7M